# Multiple Cmake_Prefix_Paths

Tags: cmake

On a project I develop on, we're using cmake to compile our service. Currently, we need to get data for Qt from 3 different locations and I'm curious if there's a way to run one cmake command over three separate ones.

What we currently use:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" -DWITH_SERVER=1 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\lib\cmake ..
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" -DWITH_SERVER=1 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\protobuf\src ..
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" -DWITH_SERVER=1 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\protobuf\cmake\build\Release ..
```

We've attempted to pass the same flag 3 times and separating the paths with `:` and `;`, but none seem to work as expected.

Comment: Do you need multiple entries in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or I misunderstood you? If so then use `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\lib\cmake;C:\protobuf\src;C:\protobuf\cmake\build\Release"`

Comment: Yes, I need to have multiple entries for the prefix path. When I tried that earlier it didn't seem to work as expected, ending after the first option

Comment: I've just tried it and it prints as it should: `message("!!!!!! " ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})` Running with the aforementioned string produces the following: `!!!!!! C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\lib\cmakeC:\protobuf\srcC:\protobuf\c??make\build\Release` Note the question marks in the 3rd path. Something is not right with the string - seems like some unicode character there

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To provide multiple paths in the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable you need to delimit each entry by `;`(semicolon). So your command will look like:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\lib\cmake;C:\protobuf\src;C:\protobuf\c‌​make\build\Release"
```

To check if everything alright with the provided paths you can use the following code in the cmake file:

```
foreach(path ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
  message("Path: " ${path})
endforeach(path)
```

It will print every path provided.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Jenkins 2.60.2 and CMake 3.9.1.

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/Olumide/src/project/Release/install/lib/cmake;/home/Olumide/src/project/Release/cmake .` does not work in cmake version: 3.19.1. (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

Comment: Commenting on the comment. It didn't work because you are missing the quotes

Comment: @Olumide commenting on the comment on the comment: when you don't use quotes around `-D...=...;...`, the shell can interpret special characters instead of treating them as part of a string literal. [In bash, `;` is a command separator](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html).

Comment: Another option to get it to work might be to put the first quote right at the start: `"-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/1;/path/2"` (needed this on linux with cmake 3.7.1)